# laravel leftjoin on json

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have Raw query running as

```
select meeting.id, GROUP_CONCAT(users.name separator " | ") AS present_user_id from `meeting` left join `users` on JSON_CONTAINS(meeting.present_user_id, JSON_ARRAY(users.id), '$') group by `meeting`.`id`
```

Which provide proper result, I tried to convert same in Laravel 8 like this

```
DB::table('meeting')
->selectRaw(' meeting.id, GROUP_CONCAT(users.name separator " | ") AS present_user_id')
->leftJoin('users', DB::raw("JSON_CONTAINS(meeting.present_user_id, JSON_ARRAY(users.id), '$')", DB::raw(' '), DB::raw(' ')))
->groupBy('meeting.id')
->get();
```

This create query as

```
select meeting.id, GROUP_CONCAT(users.name separator " | ") AS present_user_id from `meeting` left join `users` on JSON_CONTAINS(meeting.present_user_id, JSON_ARRAY(users.id), '$') = `` group by `meeting`.`id`
```

So Laravel add ( = `` ) at the end of join which I don't want and want to remove let me know how can I achieve it. I do want to use QueryBuilder only.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, writing it with laravel's QueryBuilder does not provide any readability or code enhancement. I would K.I.S.S.:

```
$result = DB::select('
   select 
     meeting.id, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(users.name separator " | ") AS present_user_id 
   from `meeting` 
   left join `users` on JSON_CONTAINS(meeting.present_user_id, JSON_ARRAY(users.id), \'$\') 
   group by `meeting`.`id`
');
```

Comment: Wouldn't the select need to be wrapped in `DB:raw('select meeting.id ...')` to work? Also... this would bypass all of the query builder functionality he might want (like dynamically adding where statements)

Comment: There is no need to wrap it in `raw` statement, it works as it is. You could definitly argue that the query is less extendable, but again, if you are going to do joins on `json_contains`, the query builder just is more work to write, read and implement. If the query has to be `AS IS`, then this solution fits quiet well

Comment: i 100% agree that the query builder is more work. And I've used your solution hundreds of times (but always with DB::raw() wrapping the query inside of the select). I did find this https://github.com/rexshijaku/sql-to-laravel-builder which converts the query into the laravel query builder code... but it would require running eval() which is a bad idea. The underlying logic of that package should work to actually create a query builder instance from a raw sql query but its not there yet... guess ill fork the repo and try to improve it.

Comment: That looks like a very nice package indeed. If you got the time, sure fork and improve it :) There is definitly a need for a tool like this

Comment: https://laraveltesting.itulbuild.com/documentation/sql-to-laravel Package is built and tested... This package will convert any raw sql string to a laravel query builder class and allow it to be modified. This was done in a few hours so it might not be perfect. But I think this package is the best of both worlds between your suggestion and mine.

Answer (score 0):

--- UPDATE ---

I put together a quick package to turn raw sql into a laravel query builder object.

https://laraveldocs.itulbuild.com/documentation/sql-to-laravel

**INSTALL**

```
composer require itul/sql-to-laravel
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
//ORIGINAL RAW SQL
$sql = "select meeting.id, GROUP_CONCAT(users.name separator \" | \") AS present_user_id from `meeting` left join `users` on JSON_CONTAINS(meeting.present_user_id, JSON_ARRAY(users.id), '$') group by `meeting`.`id`";

//CONVERT TO A LARAVEL QUERY BUILDER OBJECT
$query = \Itul\SqlToLaravel\SqlToLaravel::convert($sql);

//THE QUERY CAN NOW BE USED AS IF IT WAS NATIVELY WRITTEN IN LARAVEL FORMAT
$query->where('meeting.id', '>=', 100);

//GET THE RESULTS
dd($query->get());
```

--- ORIGINAL ANSWER ---

Without having access to your database... I suspect the issue is that ->leftJoin requires all 4 parameters and you're passing the last 2 as blank.

Maybe try

```
DB::table('meeting')
->selectRaw(' meeting.id, GROUP_CONCAT(users.name separator " | ") AS present_user_id')
->leftJoin('users', DB::raw("JSON_CONTAINS(meeting.present_user_id, JSON_ARRAY(users.id), '$')", DB::raw('IS NOT'), DB::raw('NULL')))
->groupBy('meeting.id')
->get();
```

This is just a guess since there isnt enough info.

If that doesnt work... try sharing some records from your database.